# Javascript: Storing objects as values in a hash

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm very new to javascript, I'm not sure if its possible to do this.

I'm trying to store Chart objects (from [Chartjs.org](http://www.chartjs.org/)) as the value in a hash, the keys are strings. When the following code is run I get an error that reads 'Object [object Object] has no method 'Line'.

Any advice?

```
var charts = {};

function drawChart(response, div_id){
  data = {
    labels: response.labels,
    datasets: [{...},{...}]
  };

  options = {...};


  var canvas = document.getElementById(div_id);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  if(!charts[div_id]){
    charts[div_id] = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);    
  }
  else{
    charts[div_id].Line(data, options);
  }
}
```

Comment: Site note for the term "hash": The hash function is not injective in general (different objects may have the same hash). So its not a hash you want to store your objects in.

Comment: So you're calling `.Line` when you store the data into your charts object. What does `.Line` return? Because if it doesn't return the chart itself, then yes, when you try to get the data back about (inside your `else`), then the object you get won't have a `Line` function, resulting in the error you see. Can you post the relevant code for the `Chart` function and anything related to its prototype? Have you narrowed down yet whether the error is coming from the `if` or the `else`? Either one could throw the error you mention.

Comment: It sounds like `div_id` is not a string value.  Put a `alert(typeof div_id)` in your code.  IF this is the case, then the assignment o `charts[div_id]` will never happen, and thus there will never be a method called `Line`.

Comment: @tampis Hash is the wrong tag for javascript objects. Indeed, they are hashtable-like in their implementation (chiefly with `O(1)` string-index lookup) but they are also so much more than a hashtable.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher `alert(typeof div_id)` prints `string`

Comment: @agarrow - What is the value of the string then?  If it is ` [object Object]` (per your question) then it is getting stringified somewhere.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher the value of the string is usually something like 'usa_bound_commercial', and the alert will print that if I do `alert(div_id);`

Comment: @PatrickM the error is coming form the `else`, its from chartjs.org

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher if I run `alert( charts[div_id] )` it prints `[object Object]`

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that .Line() does not return a Chart() object, so in the else section, you are doing the equivalent of Chart().Line().Line

Try rewriting like this

```
  if(!charts[div_id]){
    charts[div_id] = new Chart(ctx);  
  }

  charts[div_id].Line(data, options);
```